# npx create react app command is not working

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

i tried create react app with npx.
I written following command in terminal
npx create-react-app

after hitting enter button it shows following error.

PS C:\Users\Muhammad Hafizullah\react_project> npx create-react-app newPro
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Muhammad'
command not found: create-react-app"

Comment: Did you try npx create-react-app YOUR_APP_NAME?

Comment: **Exactly** what command did you run?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Username with spaces/symbols causes error in installation
it had happened to me
the solution to this is Creating a local admin account that's just a single string with no symbols or spaces, logging into that account, and then running the npx command worked perfectly.

Installing ReactJs on a Windows machine with a users/ path that contains spaces and or an & causes a bug to happen in which npx/npm can't properly parse the path to the module, therefore throwing a can't find module error.